# Conversion to R data.frame from SparkR dataframe is never completed for 2 million records

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, rstudio-server

I am using SparkR on R Studio server. After creating an sqlContext, I processed few tables in sparkR and am left with the final table of 2.2million records which I wanted to convert to a R data.frame in order to develop regression models using R functions. However, the code of "as.data.frame(finaltable)" never gets executed even after 2 hours due to memory issues.

```
library(SparkR) 
sc <- sparkR.init(master="yarn-client", sparkEnvir = list(spark.yarn.keytab="/home/teja_kolli/teja_kolli.keytab" , spark.yarn.principal="teja_kolli@HADOOP.QA.AWS.CHOTEL.COM",spark.driver.memory="4g" ))
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

customer_activity_bookings <- parquetFile(sqlContext, "s3a:/parquet/customer_activity_bookings/.parquet")

registerTempTable(customer_activity_bookings, "customer_activity_bookings")
```

I use similarly some 4 tables and do further processing to arrive at that below table T3 which has some 2.2 million records

```
t3 <- sql(sqlContext, 
"select a.visitor_id,a.timestamp,a.sort_number,a.property_id,a.brand_name,a.distance_value,a.guest_recommends,a.guest_reviews,a.min_avg_nightly_before_tax,a.rating_value,
a.relevance,a.relevance_distance_index,a.relevance_rate_index,a.relevance_rating_index,a.hotel_selection_type,a.pid,c.p_key,c.sum_key  
from t1 a left outer join t2 c on a.visitor_id = c.visitor_id and a.timestamp = c.timestamp where c.p_key=1 and sum_key=1")

**modeldata1<-as.data.frame(t3)**
```

The above as.data.frame takes so long to run (  throws "out of memory Java Heap space error". In the sparkR.init connection I went up to (memory = "4g") and can't go beyond due to memory restrictions.)

Is there any work around to bring this final table of 2.2 million records into R so that I can use R functions,libraries and commands?

Answer (score 1):

Converting a sparkR data frame to a local R data frame is not a good idea because you are moving all the distributed dato to one point causing a lot of networking traffic and missing the advantage of having the data distributed, maybe you should research more about the sparkR package probably there is a command for what you want to calculate

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/